# How to store and convert extreme numbers?

Tags: c#, variables, numbers, long-integer

I want to make a clicker-game for that I need to store extreme high numbers

So as far as I know in C# (which I use with Unity) can store numbers up to 9223372036854775807 which is the maximum value of a long variable.

Now in clicker games, I believe they use much bigger values than that. What would be a good way to store higher numbers and how could I possibly make a system that is sustainable for dealing with much bigger values? Or am I approaching the question from a wrong point of view?

Comment: See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114911/how-do-idle-games-handle-such-large-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here [BigInteger Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger)

> The members of the BigInteger type closely parallel those of other
>   integral types (the Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, SByte, UInt16, UInt32,
>   and UInt64 types). This type differs from the other integral types in
>   the .NET Framework, which have a range indicated by their MinValue and
>   MaxValue properties.